# Drools: Get identifier from LHS pattern

Tags: drools

I am using Drools 6.3.0 Final. Assuming I have a rule like this

```
rule "Child of Person over 18"
when
    $person : Person(age > 18)
    $child : from $person.children
then
end
```

Let us further assume I build my KieSession with this rule, add some facts and now I want to know the identifiers used in all rules / in all rules that matched my facts.

So what I want to get here is $person and $child.

I know I can get the rules, which fired using an AgendaEventListener and from the event I can get the name of the rule, as well as the objects for $person and $child. But I fail to find a way to get the identifiers $person and $child from my match. Using a debugger I can see the information is there... actually the Rule I get from the event, is a RuleImpl, which has a lhsRoot, in which I can find that information... but this sounds much more complicated than it should be and not the intended way.

So I was wondering if there is not a better way for this.

Comment: What would you want to do with this information which is purely local to a rule?

Comment: RuleImpl and GroupElement are classes of the non-public API, which means that they are subject to change without notice. The standard advice is to avoid basing any serious app programming on those classes.

Comment: I need to supply my own system for consequences, that's why I need the matched values and the names used in the rule. I was hoping there is public API for this, but if not, well, then it has to be internal

Comment: Strange - as if Java weren't enough to satisfy all needs. - But wouldn't it be easier and safer to write the RHS as a single call of some static method, passing all bound variables you need as parameters to "your own consequence"?

Comment: you mean something like record("Child of Person over 18", "$person", $person, "$child", $child)? Possible surely, yes. I have additional requirements I haven't mentioned that forbid using consequences in rules directly. Later on the rules will be generated from a completely different source than a DRL. When we are at that point I will also not have a problem extracting the identifiers anymore.

Comment: I could say something in response to that but you seem to want to progress on an utterly strange path which would render any advice moot. - Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be easily achieved by using Drools' public API. You were looking at the right place (AgendaEventListener) but  `Match.getObjects()` is not what you need. What you need is a combination of `Match.getDeclarationIds()` (to get the list of identifiers) and then `Match.getDeclarationValue(String id)` (to get the value for each identifier). As an example, this is how an AgendaEventListener that logs this information in the console will look like:

```
import org.kie.api.event.rule.BeforeMatchFiredEvent;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.DefaultAgendaEventListener;

...

ksession.addEventListener(new DefaultAgendaEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent event) {

        String ruleName = event.getMatch().getRule().getName();
        List<String> declarationIds = event.getMatch().getDeclarationIds();

        System.out.println("\n\n\tRule: "+ruleName);

        for (String declarationId : declarationIds) {
            Object declarationValue = event.getMatch().getDeclarationValue(declarationId);

            System.out.println("\t\tId: "+declarationId);
            System.out.println("\t\tValue: "+declarationValue);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
});
```

As @laune mentioned,you can also get an instance of the match that activated a rule in the RHS of the rules themselves. In this case, the Match object is accessible through `drools.getMatch()`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: My problem with getDeclarationIds() was, that it seems to return an empty list in my case